# Windows Recovery and Dual Booting

Tags: windows, partitioning, dual-boot, windows-vista

After getting a new Toshiba Portege laptop I installed Ubuntu. At the time I was very naive and I didn't completely know what dual booting meant but now I regret the decision and I'm looking to dual boot Visa along side 11.10. My original plan was to back up my files and use the Vista Recovery CDs to get windows up then reinstall Ubuntu, then select the Dual boot option. Only problem is Toshiba doesn't ship recovery CDs with their computers and paying 30 bucks for windows seems useless to me. Any suggestions as to how I can Dual boot Windows from Ubuntu?

Comment: Your issue is that you don't have a license key for Windows then? (I'm struggling to understand what you are asking)

Answer (score 2):

His issue is that Toshiba doesn't include the Vista media, although the laptop will have a valid Vista key.

John, what I recommend you do is ask a tech-savvy friend to locate a OEM Vista install CD (likely using bittorrent) and use that to reinstall windows. As your laptop came with a Vista Key sticker this is legal.

You can then setup whatever dual-boot options at a later date.

Comment: I don't understand my downvotes, but I still haven't resolved the issue (ie finding a tech savvy friend). Any suggestions on locating the OEM torrent?

Answer (score 0):

You can download Windows OS from Microsoft.  I forget now from exactly where, but you should be able to google it.  Make your CD/DVD from the ISO, and install.  It will ask for your Product Key[ should be on computer case].

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu use *grub* to manage the daul boot.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install startupmanager
```